# NGRX-Entity-Relationship Graph do not receive the selector

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, entity-relationship

I am using [ngrx-entity-relationship](https://ngrx-entity-relationship.sudo.eu/) in my angular project with @ngrx/store.

When I try to use reduceGraph inside an effect, no change occurs in the store, and when I check the devtool I see that the selector is not reaching

this is the effect code

```js
    loadPostById$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(PostActions.loadPostById),
          concatMap(({ id }) =>
            this.postService.loadPostById(id).pipe(
              map((post) => reduceGraph({
                data: post,
                selector: rootPost()
              })),
              catchError((error) => of(PostActions.loadPostByIdFailure({ error })))
            )
          )
        )
      );
```

this is the relationships code

```js
    export const rootPost = rootEntitySelector(fromPosts.selectPostsState);
    export const relPostUser = relatedEntitySelector(
      fromUsers.selectUsersState,
      'publisherId',
      'publisher'
    )
```

This is what i see in devtool, it has no selector
[image: this is what i see in the devtool]